# How do I limit content display based on Categories selected?

Tags: conditionals, advanced-conditionals

Under most circumstances this would be an easy answer, but I have a slightly trickier segment I am working with.

The following code displays the category names if they are selected in the entry:

```
<div class="project-brief open-close">
    <h3>Results Type</h3>
    <div>
        <div class="project-brief">
            <ul class="brief-list">
                <?php  $parents= array(); ?>
                {categories show_group="5"}
                <?php $parent_id = '{parent_id}'; if(!$parent_id) {$parents ['{category_id}'] = '{category_name}';} ?>
                {/categories}

                <?php foreach ($parents as $key => $parent) { ?>
                <li><a href="/projects?category=<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $parent; ?></a>
                    <ul class="brief-list-childs">
                        {categories show_group="5"}
                        {if parent_id == <?php echo $key; ?>}<li><a href="/projects?category={category_id}">{category_name}</a></li>{/if}
                        {/categories}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the client wants to hide the entire section if none are selected in the entry.

I want to wrap the entire div in a conditional that checks to see if any of the categories are checked and display it only if it is not empty.

I would say it like this, but I can't seem to get the conditional right. Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
{If category count > 1}
   ... display the content
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this still works but might be worth a try:

```
{if "{categories}{category_name}{/categories}" != ""}
```

via: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/136676/#673690

Comment: Hi Nathan, there are about ten categories in there but i'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi Nathan, this worked with one caveat. I needed to add this to the categories tag: show_group="5". Thanks for the timely help!

Comment: No worries, glad to help.